# JEST Expected: true Received: false

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, bootstrap-vue

I have a problem in testing the components.

So i want to test a modal, however, when i try to test it, i get this error

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false
```

My modal is

```
<b-modal
        id="plugin-google-analytics-webmag"
        size="lg"
        centered
        ok-only
        hide-header-close
        no-close-on-esc
        no-close-on-backdrop
        
    >
```

and my test is

```
it ('opens a modal', (done) => {
    const button = wrapper.findAll('[data-qa="button"]');
    const modal = wrapper.findAll('#plugin-google-analytics-webmag');
    expect(button.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(button.is('button')).toBe(true);
    expect(modal.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(modal.is('div')).toBe(true);

    expect(modal.isVisible()).toBe(false);
    button.trigger('click');

    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      expect(modal.isVisible()).toBe(true);
      done();
    });
```

I use the code from [How do you open a bootstrap-vue modal with vue-test-utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227464/how-do-you-open-a-bootstrap-vue-modal-with-vue-test-utils)

Do you have some suggestions?